# Client-side dynamic import from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, dynamic, import

I'm trying to create a client-side page that reads config settings from JavaScript files. I have it built in JavaScript and dynamically add scripts, but I'm converting over to TypeScript and trying to do it with dynamic import statements. It transpiles and runs fine using a development server (webpack and webpack-dev-server), but I want to run it on the local file system without a server. I just can't seem to find a combination of settings to make it work, assuming it even can. Can someone help?

The final structure I'm looking to create would be:

```
index.html
index.js
config
--userConfig.js
--vehicles
  --Sonata.js
  --Civic.js
```

where I can add new car descriptions into the vehicles folder and then change which one I want to use by changing the setting in userConfig.js

```
// config/userConfig.js
/** 
 * @typedef {object} userObj
 * @param {string} vehicle
 */

/** @type {userObj} */
export var userCfg = {
 vehicle: "Civic"
```

```
// config/vehicles/Civic.js
/**
 * @typedef {object} carObject
 * @param {string} make
 * @param {string} model
 * @param {number} maxRPM
 */

/** @type {carObject} */
export var car = {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Civic",
    maxRPM: "6500"
};
```

In the source config folder, I also have:

```
// config/vehicles/carConfig.ts
export class carObject {
    make: string;
    model: string;
    maxRPM: number;
}
```

The html and index.ts files look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">Web App Placeholder</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
// index.ts
import { userCfg } from  "./config/userConfig"
import * as carConfig from "./config/vehicles/carConfig"

var car: carConfig.carObject = new carConfig.carObject;

function showCar() {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = 
        `${car.make} ${car.model} - ${car.maxRPM}`;
}

window.onload = function () {
    loadCarConfig(userCfg.vehicle).then(showCar);
}

async function loadCarConfig(path: string) {
    let v = await import(`./config/vehicles/${path}.js`);
    car = v.car;
}
```

Lastly, the tsconfig.json and webpack.config.js are:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [ 
        "./webpack.config.js",
        "./dist"
    ]
}
```

```
// @ts-ignore

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: { filename: "bundle.js" },
    resolve: { extensions: [".ts", ".js" ]},
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts/, use: "ts-loader", exclude: /node-modules/ }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./assets",
        port: 4500
    }
};
```

Changing the vehicle property in userConfig.js to another vehicle (assuming a corresponding .js file exists) will change which properties are loaded.

Is there a good way to make this work client side without a server? Thanks

Comment: Dynamic import is a JavaScript feature.

Comment: Understood, but TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript. I would like to write it in TypeScript which will end up as JavaScript once transpiled.

Comment: "Client-side dynamic import from JavaScript" is not only an applicable subject, it is the same subject. That's all I'm intimating. Regardless, you if you don't want to bundle the file, you have to serve it.

Comment: I was looking for a way to bundle all but the files in the config folder. Guess I'll just stick with the add script method to get the desired behavior. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can do that. I don't know the config off hand, but I guarantee webpack can be be made to exclude those files